# Xcode - prevent from switching screens after building

Tags: xcode

I am working on non-UI things in my app and don't need the UI as for now, just the console. But whenever I build the project it always switches to Desktop where the simulator is, so I need to switch back to Xcode. Does anyone know how to prevent this ? I know that I could put simulator side by side with Xcode but this has to be done manually for every project which is pretty time-consumable and annoying.

Another explanation since the one above seems to be unclear:
Using ctrl -> or ctrl <- allows to move between different windows. On one of them Xcode is running in full screen. Simulator is on another. After build finishes, Xcode window is changed to different window to show Simulator. I would like to prevent it and stay in the Xcode window

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but that kind of stuff is controlled via the Preferences > Behaviours.

Comment: I don't see any option that could do it.

Comment: Don't run fullscreen and keep the simulator on the same desktop?

Comment: No. I need to run it in full screen to get rid of distractions. Btw: this does not answer the question. I want to prevent switching windows and you suggest running in the same window.

Comment: Oh well we can't always get what we want.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately. But I still have some hope!

Comment: Are you still facing it ?, I'm looking for a solution for it.